# var userMail = e.user.getEmail(); on edit google sheets not pulling email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I was using the following script on a google sheet that worked for months, but now around 1:30 PM Thursday 3/5/2020 it stopped working and pulling the user emails. I tried changing it to the second attempt, saved, and edited the cell, but nothing happened. 
(Note: I cannot share the file due to regulations.)

What was working before:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var rg = e.range;
    if (rg.getSheet().getName() == "Call Log" && rg.columnStart == 13) {
        var nextCell = rg.offset(0, -3);
        if (nextCell.getValue() == '') {
            var userMail = e.user.getEmail();
            nextCell.setValue(userMail);
        }
    }
}
```

My second attempt:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var rg = e.range;
    if (rg.getSheet().getName() == "Call Log" && rg.columnStart == 24) {
        var nextCell = rg.offset(0, 3);
        if (nextCell.getValue() == '') {
            var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
            Logger.log(email);
            nextCell.setValue(userMail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any error messages to share with us?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code") is the error code I'm getting.

Comment: It sounds like you were trying to run the function in an environment that doesn’t supply the trigger event object like out of the script editor and that won’t work

Comment: I'm not a coder so does anyone know how to generate a error code when editing the cell? I can't get an error I'm getting a blank sting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[onEdit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)  clearly states the following:

If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same G Suite domain as the user.

Comment: I am the same G Suite domain as all the users but ti still isn't working. So I'm not sure what I should be doing differently.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the new V8 runtime.  Try switching back to the previous runtime.

Comment: THANK YOU! Resolved it changing back to the previous runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Lara,
Honestly, I've never worked with google sheet functions. But it looks like their API is pretty straightforward. Based on the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file
>   "Code")

I can assume that your function doesn't consume any values. You should retrieve the **range** from another object. I found [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data) very good to start with. It looks like you first have to get your sheet using `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` and then carefully read [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

Most likely you will end up with something like:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange();
    if (sheet.getName() === "Call Log" && range.getColumn() === 24) {
        var nextCell = range.offset(0, 3);
        if (nextCell.getValue() === '') {
            var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
            Logger.log(email);
            nextCell.setValue(email);
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't test this solution. Please, give it a try or update this in the way you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It helps me a lot. I'm reading into it. I tried this and got this error when selecting run> onedit 
Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange. (line 3, file "Code")